# OOP: Why call a public method that goes on to call a private method with the same parameters?

Tags: oop

I am a relatively new programmer, maintaining a legacy codebase.  I've come across a pattern and I'm not quite sure it makes sense to me.  Assume I have a class (let's call it OutputClass) that handles writing to logfiles and creating XML files to be used by other systems.

Now in several places in the code, OutputClass is substantiated and is sent a few objects (call them A, B, and C).  So for example (this is in VB but applies to any language):

```
Call ObjectClass.WriteFile(A, B, C)
```

Then in OutputClass, I have this code:

```
Public Sub WriteFile(A as ObjType1, B as ObjType2, C as ObjType3)
    Call WriteThisFile(A, B, C)
End Sub

Private Sub WriteThisFile(A as ObjType1, B as ObjType2, C as ObjType3)
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

If we're just passing the parameters we receive in the public method as arguments to the private method, what does that accomplish exactly?  I think I understand that purpose of public vs. private, but maybe not?  TIA for any help.

Obligatory: I looked for related questions but couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Comment: FWIW, I've never seen reflection quite this redundant. Usually there's some sort of step for sanitation or validation of the parameters before passing them to the private function that's allowed to assume the input is valid / safe.

Comment: Probably just some artifact left by someone refactoring the class. `WriteFile` probably used to do something meaningful that was removed but the programmer left it there after removing all the other code.

Comment: That makes sense.  So assuming the public method doesn't do anything special, it's probably safe to remove it, make the private method public, and just have the other code call it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a full answer, but based on my experience, you never see something like this unless it's for the sake of consistency, or as an artifact after refactoring the code from something that used to do something important.

What I mean by "consistency" is if other classes also follow this pattern, but perform something useful in the `public` method before passing the parameters to the `private` method.

In a more general sense, you'll see patterns like this that make the implementation of the `public` method perform sanitation and/or validation of the parameters, which then applies the parameters to the `private` method. Then the `private` method is allowed to make assumptions like the input is valid and safe, so the implementation will be more straightforward:

```
Public Sub WriteFile(A as ObjType1, B as ObjType2, C as ObjType3)
    // perform validition and throw if invalid
    // perform sanitation
    Call WriteThisFile(A, B, C)
End Sub

Private Sub WriteThisFile(A as ObjType1, B as ObjType2, C as ObjType3)
    // relatively simple application logic goes here
    // because assumptions can be made about input
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pattern like this as such. The most likely reason is it is leftovers from code refactoring. It could well be that tese two functions might be doing quite different things (or same thing differently). Someone realized that (sure it's confusing) and tried to unify them.

They could have eliminated the public function and made the private public but they let it stay just because its legacy code and out of abundance of caution, they let both functions stay if they need them after all at some point.